# Running tsung_stats from tsung and getting Symbol not found: _Perl_xs_handshake error

Tags: multithreading, perl, erlang, stress-testing, tsung

I am trying to produce an output using `tsung_stats`, however whenever I run the command:

`/usr/local/Cellar/tsung/1.7.0/lib/tsung/bin/tsung_stats.pl --stats /Users/Chris/.tsung/log/20181031-2312/tsung.log`

The following happens:

> warn, last interval (7) not equal to the first, use the first one (10)
>
> No data for Bosh
>
> No data for Match
>
> No data for Event
>
> No data for Async
>
> No data for Errors
>
> dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _Perl_xs_handshake
>   Referenced from:
>   /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.28.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/Template/Stash/XS/XS.bundle
>   Expected in: flat namespace
>
> dyld: Symbol not found: _Perl_xs_handshake   Referenced from:
>
> /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.28.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/Template/Stash/XS/XS.bundle
>   Expected in: flat namespace
>
> Abort trap: 6

At first it was giving me this error:

> warn, last interval (7) not equal to the first, use the first one (10)
>
> No data for Bosh
>
> No data for Match
>
> No data for Event
>
> No data for Async
>
> No data for Errors
>
> Can't locate Template.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Template
>   module) (@INC contains: /Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
>   /Library/Perl/5.18
>   /Network/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
>   /Network/Library/Perl/5.18
>   /Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.2/darwin-thread-multi-2level
>   /Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.2
>   /System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
>   /System/Library/Perl/5.18
>   /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
>   /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18 .) at
>   /usr/local/Cellar/tsung/1.7.0/lib/tsung/bin/tsung_stats.pl line 571.

After searching the internet, I first ran `sudo cpan Template` and then set the environment variable `PERL5LIB` to the path of Perl (i.e. `/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.28.0`).

I am stuck and there doesn't seem to be a fix on the internet, what can be done next?

Comment: Errors like this are usually the result of installing a module using one build of Perl (`/usr/bin/perl`?), and trying to load it in another (`/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.0/bin/perl`). Make sure all the modules in the directory pointed by `PERL5LIB` were installed by the correct `perl` (e.g. by starting fresh, and making sure to use the right copy of `cpan`.).

Comment: When I try to uninstall `perl` I am getting this error: `Error: Directory not empty @ dir_s_rmdir - /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.0`. I am trying to uninstall it using the command: `brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies perl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem. Instead of `sudo cpan Template`,

execute the following

`sudo perl -MCPAN -e'shell'`

then

`install Template`

and

`quit`

It works for me

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!